# Show hidden DIV with jQuery (Not working)

Tags: javascript, jquery, overlay, show

Language: **jQuery** / **Javascript** / **PHP**

I am trying to show a hidden DIV once a user clicks on a link.

There are 3 types of actions that should take place, depending on the value inside *`data-action`* attached inside the `href` tag.

It has 3 possible values:

- shake
- bounce
- **default** (my problem)

Now using **switch**, I switch through these actions in the Javascript code.

My problem is, I can't show the hidden div I am trying to target (code under **default** is where I'm running into some trouble with).

**JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ryxcw/1/** (problem starts at line 59)

Javascript code in use:

```js
function loadBubbleActions() {
  $('#container > a').each(function () {

    switch ($(this).attr('data-action')) {
      case "shake":
        //bind shake action to bubble
        $(this).live("click", function (e) {


          var props = $.parseJSON($(this).attr('data-action-properties'));
          var ox = $(this).css('left').replace('px', '');
          var oy = $(this).css('top').replace('px', '');
          if ($('#tae').length == 0) {

            var overlay = jQuery('<div id="overlay" style="background-color: #fff !important; background-image: url(images/texture-shake.jpg);"> </div>');
            overlay.appendTo(document.body)

            $(document.body).append('<div id="tae" class="shake" style="position:absolute;opacity:1;z-index:12000;">Info goes here</div>');

            $('#overlay').click(function () {

              $('#overlay').remove();
              $('#tae').remove();

            });


            var cssWidth = ($(this).css('width').replace('px', '') / 2 - 20);
            var cssHeight = ($(this).css('height').replace('px', '') / 2 - 20);
            var ss = ($(window).width() / 2);
            var dd = ($(window).height() / 2);

            $('#tae').css('left', (ss - cssWidth) + "px");
            $('#tae').css('top', (dd - cssHeight) + "px");


            $('#tae').effect("shake", {
              times: 5
            }, 500);
          } else {
            $('#tae').effect("shake", {
              times: 5
            }, 500);

          }
        });

        break;



      case "bounce":
        //do specific action stuff here

        $(this).live("click", function (e) {
          alert("This is a bouncing post " + $(this).attr('data-link'));
        });
        break;
      default:
        //do action code for default here
        $(this).live("click", function (e) {

          divID = $(this).attr('id');

          var props = $.parseJSON($(this).attr('data-action-properties'));
          var act = $(this).attr('data-action');
          var ox = $(this).css('left').replace('px', '');
          var oy = $(this).css('top').replace('px', '');
          if ($('.panda').length == 0) {

            $("#theDIV-" + divID).show();
            $("#overlay").show();

            $('#overlay').click(function () {

              $('#overlay').remove();
              $('.panda').remove();

            });


            var cssWidth = ($(this).css('width').replace('px', '') / 2 + 400);
            var cssHeight = ($(this).css('height').replace('px', '') / 2 - 20);
            var ss = ($(window).width() / 2);
            var dd = ($(window).height() / 2);

            $('.panda').css('left', (ss - cssWidth) + "px");
            $('.panda').css('top', "100px");
          } else {
            //$('#tae').effect("shake", { times:props.shakeNumber }, 200);
          }

        });
    }
  });
}
```

I really hope someone would be able to help out, I've spent the entire night nitpicking on this thing, I could really use the guidance. Thank you so much for your time!

Once again, here is a JsFiddle for your convenience --
**JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ryxcw/1/** (problem starts at line 59)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing this

```
if ($('.panda').length==0) {
      $("#theDIV-" + divID).show();
```

but `$('.panda').length` returns 1 because

```
<div class="panda hiddenDIV" id="theDIV-77" style="position:absolute;z-index:12000;">This is the content</div>
```

exists so the action `$("#theDIV-" + divID).show();` won't run.

http://jsfiddle.net/ryxcw/2/

**ASIDE**

Where you've used `$(this).live()` you should have used `$(this).on()` (though live will still work there).

You're using data wrong. `data-action="something"` is stored in the DOM on run. You access its contents using `.data('action')` not `.attr('data-action')`

Also I have to agree with Pointy, kind of. There's not so much "a lot of things wrong with the code" but rather, you're doing a lot of things wrong.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You can't use `.live()` when you generate a jQuery object with anything other than a CSS selector string.  That is,</strike>

```
$(this).live(whatever)
```

will never work. (well that's not true; `.live()` doesn't work without a selector string *if* you're trying to delegate, but when the handler is there on the element directly it works. It's still the case that it's somewhat weird, and `.live()` is deprecated anyway :-)

Also, you seem to want to find the `<div>` by looking at the clicked element's "id" value. <strike>That doesn't make much sense, because you can't give the same "id" to two different elements (well you can but things don't work very well).</strike>  In any case, you haven't given the `<a>` tag an "id" value anyway. (*edit* - now I see; you're using the "id" on the `<a>` as *part* of the `<div>` "id".  Still, there's no "id" on that `<a>` element.)

There really are a lot of things wrong in that code. I think you should start with something a lot simpler and work up.

Comment: Thanks for that, `.live()` worked for the other actions but I have now changed them all to `$(this).click(function(e)`. Still, **the problem remains**. I can't get the hidden DIV to show. Thank you for your time. **EDIT** The actual `href` tag has an ID on the webpage, the jsfiddle was simply a quick mock-up.

Comment: @Love the code looks for elements with class "panda", and only shows the `<div>` if there are no elements with that class. Well, that `<div>` element itself has class "panda", so that code will never be run.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. The hidden DIV has the class `.panda`, I quite don't understand what I'm missing here.. **EDIT:** Hmmm, I think I got it. I should remove `if ($('.panda').length == 0) {`.. Will try this, will update you! :)

Comment: This is not true. `$(this).live(..)` works. It's not correct but it works  http://jsfiddle.net/2SMdC/1/

Comment: @popnoodles a so it fixes it up because "on" knows the context, and it's targetting that element directly anyway